# How to use Count in EF Repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have small problem when I want to use `Count()` in Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC repository.

Here's my code:

```
 public ArrayDataVM CountAll()
 {
     return _db.ArrayDatas.Count();
 }
```

It's said cannot convert int to Model. This is the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4HwE.png)

Because I want to call it in another controller like to tidy the code. Like this (this is just one of example because there are more long query) :

Before (direct to `DbContext`):

```
ViewBag.CountAll = _db.ArrayDatas.Count();
```

After (via repository):

```
ViewBag.CountAll = _adRepo.CountAll();
```

Thanks for your help :) .

Comment: Then why do you return `ArrayDataVM` from `CountAll()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:
Inside Repository:

```
public async Task<int> CountAllAsync()
{
   return await _db.ArrayDatas.CountAsync();
}
```

After (via repository):

```
 ViewBag.CountAll =await _adRepo.CountAllAsync();
```

Comment: CountAsync() work in EF Core. if you don't use ASP .Net Core or EF Core Package please use public int CountAll()
{
   return _db.ArrayDatas.Count();
}  ViewBag.CountAll =_adRepo.CountAll();

Comment: it;s work using without async because i use non core version. Thanks all :)